# Multiple 'if not in' conditions in python

Tags: python, if-statement, web-scraping

I'm using beautifulsoup to web scrape. I originally had one condition I wanted to filter out, but I have some new conditions to narrow my results. I was using:

```
if "X" not in text:
    print text
```

Everything worked fine at this point. I have been trying to add conditions with different syntaxes, but it is causing a new problem and not solving my issue. I don't get any errors, but even my original condition is no longer getting filtered out. I'm new to python and coding in general, but I couldn't find a fix for this anywhere I checked. Any advice on the proper formatting for this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you show what you were trying that didn't work out ?

Comment: Your question are too vague, My guess is that you didn't see any output, if that is the case then print the 'text' regardless of 'X' then figured out why 'X' is in 'text'.